# Convexity w.r.t. two functions?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I recently read about **convexity with respect two functions $u, v$.** I tried to look up for some definition, but I failed. That is why I am asking it here. What does it mean a function $f$ is convex with respect to $u, v$? Where can I find literature about that concept?

The paper work on smooth functions defined on [0,1]. But I'm afraid that concept is defined in a more general setting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a common concept. Do you have a reference where you read about this? Could it have been, perhaps, convexity with respect to variables $u$ and $v$, i.e. joint convexity? I'm not familiar even with convexity with respect to a single function.

Comment: You need to add more information.

Comment: Just attach the paper you're reading, that will be useful.